# How to get rid of unrecognized input from User

Tags: java, algorithm

In my case ,the users can input

```
f 0 ,f 1, f 2
p 0, p 1 ,p 2
j 0 1, j 0 2, j 1 0....(any combination of 0,1,2)
```

I use this to get the users input

```
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
             str = scanner.nextline()
```

but now I want to prevent of invalid input :like
a 0 1 ,f 0 1 ,j a 1,f0, p0 ,j 0 ,abc, f a ,p a ,j 0 a, j 0 4 ,f 9 .....
(any input besides the valid combinations )

Now ,I only have the idea of check first word (only f,p,j)--> second word (only 0,1,2)--> third word-->forth word....

But obviously this method is so stupid .

Any method is better to solve in this case?

Comment: You can use regex to match your string...`[fpa]\s[012]`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = scanner.nextLine();
    if(str.matches("[fpa]\\s[012]"))
    {
        System.out.println("true");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("false");
    }
}
```

Comment: can it detects the spacebar .j 0 1 is valid .but j01 is invaild

Comment: @evabb if you want to match j 0 1 then your regex would be `[fpa]\\s[012]\\s[012]`.